# Do HTML elements have 'hidden indexes' for the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, `document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")` returns a list of elements, and each element has an index (so the element x is the [3] in that list, for example).Do HTML elements save that index inside the element, somehow? Or they're 'unaware' of their position?

Example of the usage I'd do with that property:

You click an element with class "People", using `event.target` when `onclick`. So you want to know which position it has, in the 'People' list. Let's say it's `event.target.classNameIndex`. So once you know the index, you can do things in JavaScript.

Obviously the simple alternative I can think of this is simply picking event.target and searching it inside the `getElementsByClassName` list. Or simply giving IDs to all elements. But avoiding that would be nice.

Hope you understand my question. :)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is returning an `Array` of the selected elements, that's why they have the index - it's nothing to do with the element itself

Comment: Sure, my question is if that index can be known from the element itself.

Comment: @Leben Then maybe rephrase the question, from the title and the first paragraph the answer is just a basic no.

Comment: `let a = ['foo', 'bar']` - You're asking if 'foo' has an index outside of this Array ( to be clear, it doesn't )

Comment: Let's say somebody gave you the secret to finding the index. What exactly would you then be able to do? In other words, what is it that makes such a thing conceptually useful to you?

Comment: @Light `HTMLCollection`, not an `Array`. It is an array _like_ structure with numerical key properties and a `length` property but none of the other methods or properties of Array

Comment: Sometimes, array elements are aware of their positions.
let object1 = {
id: 1,
value: 121
}
let a = [object1, object2]
So object1 has the index inside itself.

Comment: @Light `getElementsByClassName` returns a node-list, which is an "array-like" object, but not an actual `Array`.

Comment: @Leben except the index of `object1` is `0`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I was being brief on the comment, but a valid clarification - My mistake

Comment: @Pointy Also, the index of object1 is "id - 1", which is a relative way of obtaining the index.

Comment: Anyway, answering the utility of such a 'hidden Index', well, if you have a javascript list with information of a class in CSS (let's say, class="people" html elements have values, and those values are also saved in the javascript list called "people"), you could know how one related to other easily. Instead of having to create an ID or simply having to search inside the array.

Comment: @Leben: It is linked list, no index. At least as implemented by major browsers.

Comment: @Leben With `let object1 = { id: 1, value: 121 } let a = [object1, object2]`, the index of `object1` within the `a` array is `0`, not `"id - 1"`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus well I think it's obvious that in the written case, id attribute of the object and the index inside the HTMLCollection can be related... Maybe it's not an intelligent method, but it could work perfectly. Why not.

Comment: @Leben *id attribute of the object and the index inside the HTMLCollection can be related* <-- They could be. Then again, they might not be, that being the point. Why try to create this relationship that may not be correct and certainly would need maintenance? It seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here. This is a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sure. I agree. But then, which is a more standard and intelligent way of relating indexes with elements, then? For example, in the written case.

Comment: @Leben There isn't a standard way because it's not necessary to do this in most use cases. This is similar to how most new web developers tend to give all their elements `id`s because they find it very easy to locate just the right element when they need it. However, with experience, you realize that that level of specificity makes solutions more brittle and not scalable. The better question is "Why do you think you need this capability?" Because, whatever your answer, there are better solutions than knowing an element's index or having the element know it's own index in some larger construct.

Comment: @ScottMarcus here you can see an example of relating id with html element: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks and I find it working great. (press Show Me). Anyway, I do agree it's not necessary in most use cases. I didn't pretend to say that, I was just wondering if elements have the indexes saved inside themselves, the answer is no. I guess the reason are performance and saving memory.

Comment: @Leben Yes, that is an example of that. And, as I said, it's a poor example because of how brittle it is. That's not an example of **good** code and the same results can be gotten without that element/index relationship.

Comment: @ScottMarcus if you could provide me an example of an alternative method, I'd probably learn from it. I've only seen element/index relationships to solve these issues, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

The elements are generated either dynamically or statically and are independent from everything done with them after being displayed. There are pure javascript ways of obtaining the index of an element in a array-like structure but they will most likely depend on the use of a `element.onClick` function and pairing them with other elements via some sort of selector.

Comment: I can see where you're coming and it'd probably make a nice feature but at the same time I can understand why it's not a thing. It'd be nice to have though (:

Answer (score 1):

No, for lots of reasons.

First of all, you are doing a *query* on the internal DOM structure, and the DOM tree itself might change immediately after your query. Elements can be added, moved or removed.

Furthermore, two very different queries might have overlapping results. E.g. query 1 might return:

```
[ <div id="a">, <div id="b"> ]
```

While query 2 could return:

```
[ <div id="b">, <div id="c"> ]
```

*(for simplicity I am representing the results as arrays)*
In the above, how would the element `<div id="b">` know its unique and unchanging "index", given the truly infinite amount of possible queries, not the mention the possibly variable DOM again?